# Laravel / Centos 7: Do not update changes of js file when saved

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, centos7

I'm trying to develop a website with laravel using CentosBox / Centos-7-v7.4-Web-Server-CLI-Apache2.4-PHP7. I'm having a problem, that's when I change the content of js file but when refreshing the browser, the changed content in js file is not updated.

I tried running:
`composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan config: clear`, `php artisan cache: clear`, `php artisan view: clear`

but it doesn't work.

I look forward to the help of everyone!

Comment: also try php artisan config:cache

Comment: Have you run `npm install` in the terminal?

Comment: it happens many time to me, double check you are updating the correct js file

Answer (score 1):

very simple just add  ?v=1 or any number after your js file

example

```js
<script src="jquery.js?v=1"> </script>
```